# How to catch sitemap conformation

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitemap

I am able to generate sitemap in this format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
  <url>
    <loc>http://www.Shree/AboutMe.aspx</loc>
    <lastmod>0001-01-01T12:00:00+00:00</lastmod>
    <changefreq>Always</changefreq>
    <priority>0.0</priority>
  </url>
   <url>
    <loc>http://www.Shree/Home.aspx</loc>
    <lastmod>0001-01-01T12:00:00+00:00</lastmod>
    <changefreq>Always</changefreq>
    <priority>0.0</priority>
  </url>
</urlset>
```

and I try to submit it in Google.In submit Button

```
     System.Net.WebRequest reqGoogle = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/ping?sitemap=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("http://www.Shree/SiteMap/sitemap.xml"));
 reqGoogle.GetResponse();
```

I want to Conform and catch `GoogleResponse` and display in `label`.I try:

```
label1.text= reqGoogle.GetResponse().ToString();
```

its return `System.Net.HttpWebResponse`.This is not what i want?google send any response after submit `sitemap`.Should i able to catch and display in `label`?Thanks.

//There is not any error in code when`Debug`.

Comment: @Antonia Nop want make own sitemap submitter :).Any idea?How to catch response.Thanks.

Comment: yea, I saw and delete question because it was quite clear from question what you are trying to do, but here in Croatia is a morning and holiday, so I was little sleepy ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google just returns HTTP code 200, as stated on [Submiting sitemaps](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=183669) page.

so you should do something like this

```
HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)reqGoogle.GetResponse(); 
label1.Text = resp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK ? "Sitemap received" : "Error submiting sitemap";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.I got what i want.Thanks a lot.